# cp -r is copying over files that don't exist

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, cp

I'm trying to copy the contents of one directory to another using:

```
cp -r ~/dev/testing/app/ ~/dev/app/
```

It works, but it's copying over files that don't exist (at least visually).

For instance `index.php` is not in `/dev/testing/app/`, but when I do `cp -r ~/dev/testing/app/ ~/dev/app/`  then `index.php` appears in the `/dev/app/` directory.

I may have had `index.php` in `/dev/testing/app/` at one point, but I've since deleted it. Why is it still copying over to the `/dev/app/` directory?

Comment: Does another application still have the file open? On Unix systems, deleted files aren't physically removed from the system unless and until no applications have the file open and there are no references on the filesystem such as hard links referring to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219896/how-do-the-unix-commands-mv-and-rm-work-with-open-files

Comment: @bwDraco that is true, in the literal sense that the data of an unlinked but open file can still be there, but the removed directory entry for a recursive cp to find it will not be there, so it does not seem to apply.

Comment: If he is copying from a remote system, e.g., over NFS mount, the server may still have the name in the cache as long as something has the file open.

Comment: I'm on a mac, I don't have the previous files open.

Comment: I'm just doing it locally from one folder to another